# Java convert bytes (in the form of a string) into a string

Tags: java

I'm receiving a string of bytes from my server like so:

> 60,104,101,97,100,62,60,115,99,114,105,112

How can i convert this into a readable string?

This is what I've tried to do:

```
String s = new String(json.get("msg").toString());
System.out.println("Text Decryted : " + s);
```

But this just gives me:

> 60,104,101,97,100,62,60,115,99,114,105,112

Any ideas how to accomplish this?

Comment: You're better off using something like base64 at both ends.

Answer (score 2):

Parse a byte array from it:

```
String byteString = "60,104,101,97,100,62,60,115,99,114,105,112";
String[] byteStrings = byteString.split(",");
byte[] bytes = new byte[byteStrings.length];
for (int i = 0; i < bytes.length; i++) {
    bytes[i] = (byte)Integer.parseInt(byteStrings[i]);
}
```

Then interpret the bytes as a string in a particular character set. Find out which character set you're actually using, to avoid future problems.

```
String string = new String(bytes, java.nio.charset.StandardCharsets.UTF_8);
```

The above is not very efficient by the way. Since you're already sending a string from the server, it would make more sense just to send the actual string. If you can't send the string as-is, you should [ask about that problem](http://mywiki.wooledge.org/XyProblem).